# If 5 points are necessary to determine a conic, why are only 3 necessary to determine a parabola?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, conic-sections

I've just been reading about how 5 points are necessary and sufficient to determine a conic section in Euclidean geometry (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_points_determine_a_conic). But if parabolas are conic sections, and if 3 points are sufficient to determine a parabola (since we can solve the resulting system of equations for the parabola equation's constant, coefficient of $x$, and coefficent of $x^2$), how can it be that 5 points are necessary to determine any conic section?

Comment: you can think that you lose some points for determining what kind of conic it is.

Comment: I suspect that if you know the parabola opens up/down, then you need fewer points. I bet if you just draw three points, you can find parabolas with non vertical axes of symmetry through those points.

Comment: 3 points are not sufficient to determine a parabola in any direction/ orientation (if you count rotated parabola, you need more point)

Comment: A circle is a conic section and is determined by only $3$ points. A straight line is a conic section and is determined by only $2$ points. A point is a conic section . . .

Comment: As mentioned, three points don't determine a parabola uniquely, if you allow the parabola's axis to point in any direction. See this related question: ["Locus of vertex of parabolas through three points"](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/429033/locus-of-vertex-of-parabolas-through-three-points) to see that the family of parabolas through three points is somewhat complicated to characterize.

Comment: @bof, a straight line is not a conic section

Comment: @Rasputin What, you dare to question [***Wikipedia***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#Degenerate_cases)? "The degenerate conic is either: a point, when the plane intersects the cone only at the apex; ***a straight line***, when the plane is tangent to the cone (it contains exactly one generator of the cone); or a pair of intersecting lines (two generators of the cone)."

Comment: Three points define a parabola, if you know it's a parabola. Those same three points could make a circle, hyperbola, or ellipse, as well.

Comment: @bof, Ahh ok thanks, I stand corrected (hadn't considered that the plane could be tangent to the surface of the cone)

Comment: You need four pieces of information to get a pets record (type of animal, sex, age, and owners name) but you only need two pieces information to get a female cat's record.  A female cat is a pet.  Can you see why a female cat needs only two instead of four pieces of information?

Answer (score 32):

Illustrating a comment to OP's own answer.

---

[image]

Shown is an entire *family* of parabolas through three points, indicating that three points alone do not determine a parabola.

As mentioned in my comment, a conic in the coordinate plane has five characteristics: eccentricity, scale, orientation, $x$-location, $y$-location. Our interest in *parabolas* specifies a characteristic (eccentricity $=1$); the points account for three more characteristics; and the animation cycles through the aspects of the fifth (here, *orientation*).

Comment: Hi Blue, animation is so nice.  What parabola equation do we have with variable orientation as parameter ?

Comment: @Narasimham: I'm working on how to present the derivation, but if we have $A=(0,0)$, $B=(c,0)$, $C=(b \cos A, b\sin A)$, then the parabola through $A$, $B$, $C$ whose axis is parallel to the vector $u = (\cos\theta, \sin\theta)$ has this equation: $$\begin{align}0 &= x^2 \sin A \sin^2\theta - 2x y \sin A  \sin \theta \cos\theta + y^2 \sin A \cos^2\theta \\
   &- x c \sin A \sin^2\theta + y \left(\; - b \sin^2(A-\theta) + c \cos A \sin^2\theta \;\right)\end{align}$$

Comment: Like this one Such images burn into visual memory.

Comment: Blue Beautiful!

Answer (score 2):

EDIT 1:

5 points for a conic. A parabola has $\epsilon=1, B^2 - 4 A C =0 $ that reduces number of constants/equations to 4.

$$ A x^2+ 2 \sqrt {A\,C} x y+C y^2+D x+E y= 1 $$

This can be cast into the form making $y$ subject of parabola equation :

$$ y =  (a x + b)  \pm \sqrt { c x + d  }$$

If 3 constants are fixed, a single  parameter family of parabolas is possible like in the example  graphed :

$$ y = 2 x - 5 \pm \sqrt {3 x + 2 t} $$

Only 3 constants are *not* adequate to determine a general parabola .

[image: One parameter Parabolas]

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from the image below, if you are defining a conic, it requires five points to be known. The conics below all share three points (black), but need two more to define what they are.

If we trying to simply define a parabola, it only takes three points because we know it is a parabola, and it can't possibly be a ellipse or hyperbola -- because we decided we already that we are making a parabola!

[image]

Comment: Bonnaduck.Very nice.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to Mikhail for suggesting that knowing from the beginning that the curve is a parabola allows you to determine the specific kind of parabola it is in less than five points. I believe this is the most satisfactory explanation, because given three points in a plane there is also a unique circle passing through them, since the circle equation is

$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2 = r^2 $,

so knowing three points $(x, y)$ allows us to solve for $a, b$ and $r$.

Since circles are also conic sections, clearly three points are not enough to determine whether the curve is a parabola or a circle.

Some suggested more points are necessary to know the "direction/ orientation" of the parabola. There may be something to this. In fact, I believe the extended equation for parabolas (which may be rotated) is

$Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey= F$,

so it seems that perhaps ***six*** points may be necessary to determine some parabolas? In any case, if we have that this is the form of the equation for a curve, we have not even eliminated the possibility that it is a circle until we show that either $B$, $D$, or $E$ $\neq{0}$, so this illustrates the first problem I mentioned: needing only three points was based on the initial assumption that we were dealing with a parabola.

All this raises the question of whether 5 points determine a conic section ***after*** you know you are dealing with a conic section in the first place, or before -- i.e., whether more points may be needed to determine that the curve defined by these 5 points is indeed a conic section and not some other thing altogether.

Comment: A conic section in the coordinate plane has **five** characteristics: eccentricity, scale, orientation, $x$-position, and $y$-position. Correspondingly, **five** (distinct) points will effectively pin-down each of those characteristics so that there's exactly one conic through those points. (Note: Six points are *not* needed. There *are* six unknown coefficients in the generic second-degree equation, but they can't all be zero; this allows you to divide-out by one of those coefficients, making it a "1" and leaving only five unknowns.) (continued)

Comment: A circle in the plane is determined by three points, because the term "circle" assumes up-front two characteristics: eccentricity (zero) and orientation (or, in this case, the lack thereof). Three characteristics are in play, so three points are needed. For your question, "parabola" assumes one characteristic (eccentricity = 1); four characteristics remain in play, so four points are needed to pin one down. (The "three points determine a parabola" thing is a simplified case, usually invoked for parabolas whose axis is assumed to be vertical, thereby providing orientation up-front.) (continued)

Comment: The fact that four points are needed to "determine" a parabola means that, if you only have three points identified, then there's an entire *family* of parabolas through those points, because one of the characteristics remains in play; if you take that characteristic to be orientation, then you can imagine, for each possible direction, a parabola through your three points whose axis aligns with that direction. The "Locus of vertex" reference I made earlier helps show this; I have another illustration in mind that I'll post if I can find time.

Comment: BTW: Solving for the coefficients in the second-degree polynomial is *slightly* problematic, since it's not necessarily clear from the get-go which coefficient(s) will be non-zero. A "better" approach in this regard is to use the determinant form shown in Equation (8) of the [MathWorld "Conic Section"](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConicSection.html) entry. Note that the determinant reinforces the fact that *five* points are needed, since exactly five rows of the matrix are filled with values taken from the points' coordinates.

Comment: There are six constants in $A x^2+...=0$ but multiplying them all by any non-zero constant  gives an equivalent  equation, So there are only $5$ degrees of freedom..... Given $3$ points on a conic and given that the conic is a parabola  is more info than just being given $ 3$ points..... $A x^2+B x y +C Y^2+D x+E y+F=0$ determines a parabola iff  $B^2=4 A C$ with $A,B,C$ not all $0$.