# When is there no parabola passing through three points?

Tags: contest-math, quadratics, conic-sections

I was trying to solve the following problem: Prove that a parabola does not pass through the points $(1, 2)$, $(3,4)$ and $(5,6)$.

My attempt: If these points lie on the same parabola, then we have a function $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$ such that

$f(1) = a + b + c = 2$,

$f(3) = 9a + 3b + c = 4$, and

$f(5) = 25a + 5b + c = 6$

Now if we do $f(3) - f(1)$, we find $2 = 8a + 2b$. Also if we do $f(5) - f(3)$, then we find $2 = 2b + 16a$. Then we have:

$f(3) - f(1) = f(5) - f(3)$

$8a + 2b = 16a + 2b$

$4a = 8a$

Which only makes sense if $a = 0$, so actually, this isn't a quadratic function, but a first degree one, so the three points are collinear and there is no parabola passing through them.

I was thinking that, everytime there's no parabola, then the points are collinear and I always would find $a = 0$ if I tried to solve it the way I did, but then I realized that if the points were $(0,0)$, $(0,2)$ and $(2,2)$, then my way of solving wouln't work anymore, because even though the points are not collinear, there isn't a parabola passing through them anyway. This is making me confused. When is there no parabola passing through three points? Is there a condition that should always be met? And what would be a better way of solving the question?

Comment: If the three points are not collinear, then there exists a parabola that passes through all three.

Comment: @Scene that's what I was thinking, but the example $(0,0)$, $(0, 2)$ and $(2, 2)$ does not seems to work, even though the points are not collinear, and that's what is making me confused.

Comment: Don’t assume that all parabolas have to take the form $y=ax^2+bx+c$

Comment: The three points must have distinct $x$-coordinates if you’re looking for the graph of a function $y=f(x)$.

Comment: There's a bit of an issue here in that "points lying on a parabola" is being equated with "coordinates satisfing a quadratic function of the form $y=ax^2+bx+c$ (with $a\neq0$)". Since $(0,0)$ and $(0,2)$ have the same $x$-coordinate, they won't both satisfy a function. That said, in the grand scheme of things, not all parabolas are graphs of functions. See, eg, [my answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1736999/409), which shows how three non-collinear points (such as your example) actually determine *infinitely-many* parabolas ... almost-none of which are graphs of functions.

Comment: @Blue This makes a lot of sense, thank you!! The picture helped a lot. But what I still don't get is, if the parabola isn't always the graph of a function, what is a better way to solve the problem? Should I just prove the points are collinear without mentioning quadratic functions, or is my approach still fine anyway?

Comment: @Ingrid: I can't tell if the problem intends "parabola" to *mean* "graph of a quadratic function". (This is often so when general conics have yet to be introduced. Like how, in lower grades, "number" *means* "positive whole number" until negatives, fractions, etc, come along.) If so, then your approach is pretty-much *the* approach when given three arbitrary pts. That said, it's worth noting that the *given* pts are "obviously" collinear (especially if graphed), which would've saved you time. (BTW: All of this ignores that, in certain contexts, lines are considered "degenerate parabolas". ;)

Comment: @Blue Got it, thank you!! This cleared up my confusion. Is it ok to leave the question unanswered? I don't think it needs an answer anymore, since the comments already answered everything.

Comment: By inspection, the two last points are translates by (1,1) of the first. It follows, that they  are on a line. There are  no lines with more than two points on a quadric, sincea quadratic equation has at most two zeros if moving or rotating its graph  around in the plane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments, not all parabolas are graphs of functions. Since $(0,0)$
and $(0,2)$ have the same $x$-coordinate, they won't both satisfy a function, but this doesn't mean there's not a parabola passing through them. Three non-collinear points determine infinitely-many parabolas, so even if the points do not satisfy a function, they all lie on a parabola anyway.