# Solving 4th degree(quartic) polynomial with all irrational roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I'm a self-learner trying to solve polynomial equations.

This equation $$x^4-6x^3+\frac{31} 4x^2-\frac 3 2x-2=0$$ has $4$ irrational roots (if I'm right.) I found the solution by on-line solver. HOWEVER, I want to solve this by hand, without graphing calculator, and without using quartic formula.

Can it be done?
If so, how?
Is the procedure efficient, or should I rely on electronic devices?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "solve" - do you want to calculate the roots, or just prove that they're all irrational? (I would normally assume the former)

Comment: There are roots in $(0,1)$ and $(-1,0)$

Comment: Yes Zev, the former is what I meant. Lab, I don't understand your comment. As far as I know any root of a polynomial should be a number(be it rational or irrational) not an interval.

Answer (score 1):

Great question I believe! You probably know this but this is said in MacTutor's [Quadratic, cubic and quartic equation](http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/HistTopics/Quadratic_etc_equations.html).

> "After Tartaglia had shown Cardan how to solve cubics, Cardan
>   encouraged his own student, Lodovico Ferrari, to examine quartic
>   equations. Ferrari managed to solve the quartic with perhaps the most
>   elegant of all the methods that were found to solve this type of
>   problem. Cardan published all 20 cases of quartic equations in Ars
>   Magna. Here, again in modern notation, is Ferrari's solution of the
>   case: x4 + px2 + qx + r = 0. First complete the square to obtain
>
> [ ... ]
>
> In the years after Cardan's Ars Magna many mathematicians contributed
>   to the solution of cubic and quartic equations. Viète, Harriot,
>   Tschirnhaus, Euler, Bezout and Descartes all devised methods.
>   Tschirnhaus's methods were extended by the Swedish mathematician E S
>   Bring near the end of the 18th Century."

I just wanted to put it here to emphasize how "non-trivial" the problem of solving quartic equations can be. (I believe that you are aware of methods of finding rational roots, Uspensky's *Theory of Equations* is a great reference for that; but the general problem is definitely non trivial).

[Here](http://ijpam.eu/contents/2011-71-2/7/7.pdf) are many of this methods explained. I also found some of them [here](http://nptel.iitm.ac.in/courses/111101001/downloads/Lecture23.pdf).

Comment: In addition, it leads eventually to the Group Theory.

Comment: Thank you for the reference, I'll check them out ;)

Answer (score 1):

One method to solving the general quartic entails factoring it into two quadratics, but you will need to solve an intermediate cubic. First, given,

$$x^4+Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx+D = 0$$

let $x = y+t$ for some $t$ and new variable $y$,

$$(y+t)^4+A(y+t)^3+B(y+t)^2+C(y+t)+D = 0$$

Expand and collect the variable $y$,

$$y^4+(A+4t)y^3+\dots = 0$$

Let $t = -A/4$ to get rid of its $y^3$ term to get the *depressed form*,

$$y^4+py^2+qy+r=0\tag{1}$$

Assume it can be factored as,

$$(y^2+ay+b)(y^2-ay+c) = y^4+(-a^2+b+c)y^2-a(b-c)y+bc = 0\tag{2}$$

Equate coefficients of $(1)$ and $(2)$,

$$\begin{aligned}
p &= -a^2+b+c\\
q &= -a(b-c)\\
r &= bc
\end{aligned}\tag3$$

Solving for $b,c$, you will end up with a cubic in $a^2$. Once you have $a,b,c$, you can then solve,

$$y^2+ay+b = 0$$
$$y^2-ay+c = 0$$

which should give you the 4 roots of $(1)$.

Tedious, yes, but at least now you know how to solve the general quartic. (Though it means first knowing how to solve the general cubic.)

Comment: Great answer! Though, why should one know how to solve the general cubic first?

Comment: @CauchytheDog: The system $(3)$ is 3 equations in 3 unknowns $a,b,c$. Solving for $b,c$, one gets a cubic in $a^2$, $$a^6+2pa^4+(p^2-4r)a^2-q^2=0$$ and that is why one needs to solve a cubic first. If you want to bypass this step, see [this solution](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1219804/4781).