# How do I factorise $r^4+r^2+1$?

Tags: factoring

How do I factorise $r^4+r^2+1$ ?
$(r^2+r+1)(r^2-r+1)$ gives $r^4+r^2+1$
But how to split it into these factors?
I generally find roots and then write the factors, but $r^4+r^2+1$ seems to have no real root.
Thanks!

Comment: I found this article which might be of some use: http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/73220.html and this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487060/solving-4th-degreequartic-polynomial-with-all-irrational-roots

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One may start with
$$
r^4+r^2+1=(r^4+2r^2+1)-r^2=(r^2+1)^2-r^2.
$$

Answer (score 5):

$$x^4+x^2+1=\frac{x^6-1}{x^2-1}=\frac{(x^3-1)(x^3+1)}{(x-1)(x+1)}
=(x^2+x+1)(x^2-x+1).$$