# How do I solve this equation; $x^4+4x-1=0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quartics

I know that I can easly solve this with the $4$th degree's equation, but isn't there a smarter way? It is an olympiad's problem so it shouldn't be a formula, but more find a formula... I have remarked that it is equal to $(x^2+1)\cdot(x+1)\cdot(x-1)+4x=0$ It isn't just solving the equation, I want to know if it can be solved otherwise than that... Could someone explain why this is equal to $(x^2+1)^2-(\sqrt{2}(x-1))^2$ please ?

Comment: It's actually equal to all that $+4x$, not $-4x$.  Maybe just a typo, though.

Comment: What is the olympiad question ? Solve the equation ?

Comment: @tilper Yes I will edit it...

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Yes...

Comment: Factorise into two quadratics

Comment: Not number theory, surely.

Comment: @Macavity Yea you're right... What should I then put?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom : O.k. :-)

Comment: @DanielAlberten: See (22) in [Quartic Equation of mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuarticEquation.html).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a general formula for solving 4th degree equations?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/785/is-there-a-general-formula-for-solving-4th-degree-equations)

Comment: No, I want to find a formula that just resolves this equation... Not even a formula but an easy way of find the solution...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may write it as
$$ x^4+4x-1=(x^2+1)^2-2(x-1)^2 =  (x^2+1)^2-(\sqrt{2}(x-1))^2$$
and factorize.

Comment: Why is this correct?

Comment: @DanielAlberten you have to learn to ask the right questions.  Presumably, you are not asking how to *verify* that the solution is correct, but how one would come up with it in the first place.

Comment: @H.H.Rugh How did you think to apply this trick to this problem?  Is it a well-known approach?

Comment: Sort of. If a quartic equations is 'solvable' in finite time, it should be a product of 'identifiable' quadratics and the easiest ones are those that factors into $p^2-q^2$. Then look for $p$ and $q$. That works here (it helps on the guessing work that there are no $x^3$ nor $x^2$). If not, it gets more messy.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to rely on tricks (tricks are always useful though), a more systematic approach is as follows. Let
$$x^4+4x-1 = (x^2+ax+b)(x^2+cx+d)$$
We then have
\begin{align*}
a+c & = 0\\
b+d+ac & = 0\\
bc + ad & = 4\\
bd & = -1
\end{align*}
Eliminating $c$, we obtain
\begin{align*}
b+d & = a^2\\
d-b & = \dfrac4{a}\\
bd & = -1
\end{align*}
This gives us $d = \dfrac{a^2}2 + \dfrac2a$ and $b = \dfrac{a^2}2 - \dfrac2a$. Since $bd=-1$, we obtain
$$\dfrac{a^4}4 - \dfrac4{a^2} = -1 \implies a^6 - 16 = -4a^2$$
Setting $a^2=y$, we have
$$y^3+4y - 16 = 0$$
By rational root theorem, we find that $y=2$ as one root. The other two roots are complex and hence we are not interested in them. This gives us $a=\pm \sqrt2$. Taking $a=\sqrt2$, we see $c=-\sqrt2$. This gives us
$$d=1+\sqrt2 \text{ and }b = 1-\sqrt2$$
Hence, we obtain the factorization as
$$x^4+4x-1 = (x^2+\sqrt2 x+1-\sqrt2)(x^2-\sqrt2 x+1+\sqrt2)$$

Answer (score 2):

There is a tricky way since our polynomial can be easily written as a difference of two squares:
$$ (x^2+1)^2-2(x-1)^2 = \left[x^2+x\sqrt{2}+(1-\sqrt{2})\right]\cdot \left[x^2-x\sqrt{2}+(1+\sqrt{2})\right]\tag{1}$$
hence by the quadratic formula the roots are given by 
$$ -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\pm\sqrt{\sqrt{2}-\frac{1}{2}},\qquad \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\pm i\sqrt{\sqrt{2}+\frac{1}{2}}.\tag{2} $$

Comment: But how is it the difference of 2 squares?

Comment: @DanielAlberten: because $2=\sqrt{2}^2$.