# What is the positive real root of the equation $x^4-x-1=0$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I tried to solve the question on the graph and got two roots also I used Newton Raphson rule but a general proof is required. Any kind suggestions will be appreciated.
Also the root = √√(1+√√(1+√√(1+√√(1+... hence when I solved this on my calculator I got the root but I don't know whether there is a closed form for it or not

Comment: There is a closed form, [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E4+-+x+-+1) will show it to you, if you click the "exact form" button. They're pretty nasty, though.

Comment: See this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/785/is-there-a-general-formula-for-solving-4th-degree-equations-quartic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to wolfram alpha, exact form of this solutions are

[image]

The former is positive solution.