# Solve for x :$\tan x-\sin x+\tan x-1=0$ where $x\in[0,2\pi]$

Tags: trigonometry

The best progress I could make was to arrive at a degree 4 polynomial in $\cos x$:
$-\cos^4 x-4\cos^2x+4\cos^3x-4\cos x+4=0$. But I couldn't factor it out so that I can find the value of $\cos x$ and thus $x$.
Can anyone please help me to factor the polynomial or suggest an alternate method to solve the problem[image]

Comment: $\tan x$ appears twice?

Comment: Please put the full question in the question, not the title.  As of yet, you haven't told us what the problem is.

Comment: I just typed it into [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2tan(x)-sin(x)%3D1) and did not get a symbolic answer.  That doesn't prove there isn't one, but it is indicative.

Comment: @RossMillikan Actually, I'm thinking it should be clear that this can be reduced to a quartic of either $\sin$ or $\cos$, and all quartics have closed forms... (doesn't mean its pretty, but they have one)

Comment: However, the given quartic is wrong... hence why we recommend the showing of work.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: true, and OP did, but seemed to be looking for a simpler approach.

Comment: I have attatched my work, but as Ross Milikan said I am looking for a simpler approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given quartic is not equivalent to the problem in the title.  One may note that

$$2\tan x-\sin x+1=0\\2\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}-\sin x+1=0\\2\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}=1-\sin x\\4\frac{\sin^2x}{\cos^2x}=1-2\sin x+\sin^2x$$

Now use the Pythagorean identity to see that

$$4\frac{\sin^2x}{1-\sin^2x}=1-2\sin x+\sin^2x$$

Or,

$$4\sin^2x=1-2\sin x+2\sin^3x-\sin^4x$$

> $$t=\sin x\implies0=t^4-2t^3+4t^2+2t-1$$

Now there are several approaches to factoring quartics.  I won't go through the details, but [you can read up on them here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/785/is-there-a-general-formula-for-solving-4th-degree-equations-quartic).

More or less, I recommend applying [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0+%3D+x%5E4+%2B+ax%5E3+%2B+bx%5E2+%2B+cx+%2B+d), then extract desired solutions.

Answer (score 0):

use $$\sin(x)=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$$
$$\tan(x)=\frac{2t}{1-t^2}$$ and $$\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)=t$$