# Help in factorization

Tags: factoring

So  I was thinking that how can I factorize $x^4-2x^2-8$, or any $4$ degree polynomial, without going for the first factor by trial and error method?

Comment: There are formulas for quartics but they're too unwieldy and unstable.

Comment: There is in fact a (*very lengthy and tedious*) general form you can use for solving for the roots of fourth-degree polynomials but noone learns or memorizes it due to its incredibly unwieldy nature.  In your very specific case however, there is a nice way to simplify the problem first and use what you know about quadratics by replacing $x^2$ by something else, lets call it $u$.  So, $x^4-2x^2-8=(x^2)^2-2(x^2)-8=u^2-2u-8$.  Now, you can solve for $u$.  Given the solutions for $u$, you can then go back and replace with $u=x^2$ again and solve for $x$.

Comment: As an aside, it has been proven thanks to Galois Theory that there does not and can not exist a general solution for the roots of *arbitrary* degree five or higher polynomials (*though as usual, special cases occur and can have very clean answers*).  [Link for arbitrary degree 4 solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots).

Comment: If you need an explicit formula, check out the third answer on this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/785/is-there-a-general-formula-for-solving-4th-degree-equations-quartic Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

$$x^4-2x^2-8=x^4-2x^2+1-3^2=(x^2-4)(x^2+2)=(x-2)(x+2)(x^2+2).$$

We can make factorization for all $4$ degree polynomial over $\mathbb R$ by the Ferrari's method.

Answer (score 1):

Express the function as a quadratic in $x^2$

$(x^2)^2 - 2x^2 -8$

Factor it for $x^2$

$(x^2+2)(x^2-4)$

Write 4 as $2^2$ and expand it,

$(x^2+2)(x+2)(x-2)$

Comment: Small typo after the first factorization.  The second plus should be a minus.

Comment: Thanks @Mike .. corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x^2=y$.

Then you have to factorize $y^2-4y-8=P(y)$

$P(y)=(y-2- \sqrt{12})(y-2+ \sqrt{12})$

Thus $$x^4-4x^2-8=(x^2-2- \sqrt{12})(x^2-2+ \sqrt{12})=$$ $$(x+ \sqrt{2+ \sqrt{12}})(x-\sqrt{2+ \sqrt{12}})((x^2-2+ \sqrt{12})$$