# What is $x$ if $\sqrt{x+4+2\sqrt{x+3}}=\frac{x+8}{3}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals, nested-radicals

I need to find $x$, given that
$$\sqrt{x+4+2\sqrt{x+3}}=\frac{x+8}{3}$$
I simplified this to $x^4+14x^3+105x^2+68x-188=0$. According to [Symbolab](https://www.symbolab.com/), that is not correct. That's why I'm goint to write out my attempt so you can point out where my mistake is.

---

*My attempt*

$$\sqrt{x+4+2\sqrt{x+3}}=\frac{x+8}{3}$$
$$\left(\sqrt{x+4+2\sqrt{x+3}}\right)^2=\left(\frac{x+8}{3}\right)^2$$
$$x+4+2\sqrt{x+3}=\frac{x^2+16x+64}{9}$$
$$9x+36+18\sqrt{x+3}=x^2+16x+64$$
$$-x^2-7x-28=-18\sqrt{x+3}$$
$$x^2+7x+28=18\sqrt{x+3}$$
$$(x^2+7x+28)^2=(18\sqrt{x+3})^2$$
$$x^4+7x^3+28x^2+7x^3+49x^2+196x+28x^2+196x+784=324x+972$$
$$x^4+14x^3+105x^2+68x-188=0$$
Where is my mistake? Even if this were true, I still wouldn't be able to solve it without a calculator (I can't use [Rational Root Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) on such a big numbers!).

---

By the way, the solution should be (again, according to [Symbolab](https://www.symbolab.com/)) $x \in \{1,-2\}$.

Comment: You *can* use the rational root theorem, which suggests that you check (among others, so why not first?) $\pm1$ and $\pm2$. Checking that $1+14+105+68-188=0$ and $16-112+420-136-188=0$ is straigtforward, so you find $1$ and $-2$ as roots. After that, you are left with a quadratic

Comment: To find all possible solutions, take a look at the quartic equation problem in here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's $$\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{x+3}+x+3}=\frac{x+8}{3}$$ or
$$\sqrt{\left(1+\sqrt{x+3}\right)^2}=\frac{x+8}{3}$$
$$1+\sqrt{x+3}=\frac{x+8}{3}$$ or
$$\sqrt{x+3}=\frac{x+5}{3}$$ and since $x\geq-3$, it's
$$9(x+3)=(x+5)^2,$$
which gives $x=1$ or $x=-2.$.

Comment: +1 Nice trick! :)

Comment: I don't get it. How did you go from the original equation to any of the derived ones?

Comment: @Hanlon I used $x+4=1+x+3$, $(\sqrt{x+3})^2=x+3$ and $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2.$ I added something. See now.

Answer (score 2):

What you did is fine. Now, you can use the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) in order to find the roots $1$ and $-2$. Since your polynomial is $(x-1)(x+2)(x^2+13x+94)$, there are no more real roots. Note however that you still must check whether or not $-2$ and $1$ are solutions of the original equation.

Answer (score 0):

You can brutally use Ferrari formula but no need here.

Search for obvious Roots , here 1 is clearly an obvious Roots then factorise by :

$$X-1$$

And try again with obvious roots. $0;1;2;-1,i,-i$

Comment: But where is my mistake? Or is Symbolab wrong?

Comment: No mistake ! Just plug 1 in your équation and verify ! As I suggest in general try obvious roots to factorize

Comment: What kind of formula is "Ferrari formula"? I can't find anything about it.

Comment: Think it is better known in France just look at formula there https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9thode_de_Ferrari

Comment: I translate the original idea for cultural knowledge: you replace $z^4$ by $ (z^2+y^2)^2-2yz^2-y^2 $ where $y$ is a parameter to fix further then you factorize  your original equation (like the expression above) and identify y.

Answer (score 0):

Your question was how to determine the value of $x$ in the given equation: 
$$
\sqrt{x+4+2\sqrt{x+3}}=\frac{x+8}{3}
$$

1.) 
$
x+4+2 \sqrt{x+3} = \bigg( \frac{x+8}{3} \bigg)^2
$

2.) 
$
x+4+2 \sqrt{x+3} =  \frac{x^2+8^2}{3^2}
$

3.) 
$
9(x+4+2 \sqrt{x+3}) =  (x+8)^2
$

4.) 
$
9x+36+18 \sqrt{x+3} =  (x+8)(x+8)
$

5.) 
$
18 \sqrt{x+3}) =  (x^2+16x+64)-9x-36
$

6.) 
$
\sqrt{x+3}) =  \frac{x^2+7x+28}{18}
$

7.) 
$
x+3 =  \bigg( \frac{(x^2+7x+28)({x^2+7x+28})}{18 \times 18} \bigg)
$

8.) 
$
x+3 =  \frac{x^4+14x^3+105x^2+392x+784}{324}
$

9.) 
$
324x+972 =  x^4+14x^3+105x^2+392x+784
$

10.) 
$
x^4+14x^3+105x^2+68x=188
$

---

**The outcome of the equation is that it is a $4^ \text{th}$ degree polynomial** of the form
$
a_1x^4+a_2x^3+a_3x^2+a_4x+a_4=0
$

$$
x^4+14x^3+105x^2+68x-188=0
$$

The solution given by my [calcuator](https://www.casio.com/products/calculators/graphing/fx-9750giibu) is:

$
x_1=1,
x_2=-2
$

To find out how that comes about, refer to [Quartic polynomial solutions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/786/540632)

Comment: You reproduced the same OP calculations. There is nothing new in your answer.

Comment: Then that proves the OP was correct but I went further to prove it using my own work that the answer was correct and added a reference to improve the OP's understanding of why which is exactly what was asked.