# Quartic Equation with a single variable

Tags: polynomials, quartics

So, I got some tasks from my lecturer about quartic and even quintic equation

[Here is the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryc7C.png)

I tried using some general solution for quartic from this link

[Is there a general formula for solving 4th degree equations (quartic)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/785/is-there-a-general-formula-for-solving-4th-degree-equations-quartic)

I failed and the equation become more and more complex. Anyone can help me with this?

Comment: Yes there is a general formula.  But in practice you need [a multistep process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Polynomialdeg4.svg).

Comment: can you tell me more about multistep process? or maybe drop a reference link to it. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving $$x^4 + 4 a x^3 + 6 x^2 + 4 a x + 1 = 0$$
Divide all terms by $x^2$
$$x^2+4ax+6+\frac{4a}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}=0$$
Osserve that we can write the previous equation as
$$\left(x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}+2\right)+4a\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)+4=0$$
That is
$$\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^2+4a\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)+4=0$$
Set $w=x+\frac{1}{x}$. The equation becomes
$$w^2+4aw+4=0$$
Solutions are
$$w_1=-2a-2 \sqrt{a^2-1};\;w_2=-2a+2 \sqrt{a^2-1}$$
Bringing beack the $x$ we have the equations
$$x+\frac{1}{x}=-2a-2 \sqrt{a^2-1};\;x+\frac{1}{x}=-2a+2 \sqrt{a^2-1}$$
Reordering etc
$$x^2 + \left(2a+2 \sqrt{a^2-1}\right)x+1=0;\;x^2 + \left(2a-2 \sqrt{a^2-1}\right)x+1=0$$
Whose solutions are
$$x_1=-a-\sqrt{a^2-1}-\sqrt{2 a^2-2+2 a\sqrt{a^2-1} };\;\\x_2=-a-\sqrt{a^2-1}+\sqrt{2 a^2-2+2 a\sqrt{a^2-1}};\;\\x_3=-a+\sqrt{a^2-1}-\sqrt{2 a^2-2-2 a\sqrt{a^2-1} };\;\\x_4=-a+\sqrt{a^2-1}+\sqrt{2 a^2-2-2 a\sqrt{a^2-1} }$$

Comment: It somehow doesn't match with the answer given by my lecturer, but I think your work is so clear and I can't find anything wrong with it. So may it possible for both answer be right ?

Comment: @ZulvanAvivi They are. I checked and they give the same results for any $a$. By the way, the solutions are pairwise reciprocal,i.e., their product is $1$.

Comment: I see, thank you so much for your clear explanation.