# Solving $6x^4+2x^3+4x^2-6x-3=0$

Tags: quartics

I'm having some trouble solving for $x$ in the following quartic equation.

$$
0=6x^4+2x^3+4x^2-6x-3 
$$

Do you have any suggestions on how I should go about solving this equation? I tried using the rational root theorem and depressing the quartic, but I became very quickly lost.

I'd really appreciate your help! Thank you so much!

Comment: Looks like this needs the general quartic solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a general formula for solving 4th degree equations (quartic)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/785/is-there-a-general-formula-for-solving-4th-degree-equations-quartic)

Answer (score 1):

Except in few cases (obvious roots, possible factorization), I do not know many people solving quatic equations with radicals.

If you are patient, compute the [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function); in this case $\Delta=-42288$ tells that  *"the equation has two distinct real roots and two complex conjugate non-real roots"*. Good news !

Plot th function and you will notice that the real roots are close to $-0.4$ and $0.9$. From these guesses, start Newton method which will converge lika a charm.

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & -0.4000000 \\
 1 & -0.3932897 \\
 2 & -0.3932557
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.9000000 \\
 1 & 0.8900408 \\
 2 & 0.8898740 \\
 3 & 0.8898739
\end{array}
\right)$$