# Solving an equation in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a>0$. I want to solve the following equation:
$$x^2 -2x +\sqrt{1-x^2} -\left(\frac{1}{a^2}+1\right) = 0.$$

I did a plot of the function on Matlab and I see that for $a=1,2,2000,...$ etc, and I see that the function has always a solution over $[-1,1]$.

I tried the following variable change: $u= \sqrt{1-x^2}$ however, it did not work (because we obtain the same equation).

Comment: Do you want to find some explicit solution or show the existence of a solution?

Comment: Yes, I want to find an explicit solution.

Comment: The equation does have [explicit solutions](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+x%5E2+-2x+%2B%5Csqrt%7B1-x%5E2%7D+-%28%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Ba%5E2%7D%2B1%29+%3D+0.), but they are fairly complicated.

Comment: @AnneBauval you are right! it is over $[-1,1]$

Comment: @L.F. that's what I found using MAPLE. A very complicated (not explicit one)

Comment: What I sent you *is* an explicit solution in mathematical terms.  Complicatedness has nothing to do with explicitness.  Moreover, I consider it highly likely that there are no (fundamentally) simpler forms.

Comment: WolframAlpha gives explicit solution, it looks complicated because it is expression of kind $x_i=f(a)$. Of course this solution can be written in shorter form with separating of repeating parts like $x_i=g(d,e)$, where $d=h(a)$, $e=i(a)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $c= 1+ \frac{1}{a^2}$ then your equation can be written as $$x^2-2x-c= -\sqrt{1-x^2}$$
By squaring both sides we get
$$ x^4 - 4 x^3 - 2 c x^2 + 5 x^2 + 4 c x + c^2 - 1=0$$
which is a quartic equation and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/785/is-there-a-general-formula-for-solving-quartic-degree-4-equations) you can see how to solve them.

To determine if the roots are real use the  properties of discriminant $Δ = 256 c^4 - 128 c^3 - 1520 c^2 - 1536 c - 848$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X=x-1$ and $b=2+\frac1{a^2}$, [solve the quartic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Solution_methods) (in $[-2,0]$)
$$X^4+(1-2b)X^2+2X+b^2=0.$$